# Cast - string to Custom<string>

Tags: c#

I have a custom wrapper object for my properties: `MyType<t>`.
I have private members of these types and public members of type t.

I'm trying to load the object and am getting a cast error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'Model.MyType`1[System.String]

I have a method for the following:

```
private t _value;

public static implicit  operator t(MyType<t> obj)
{
    return obj._value;
}
```

Any help in what I'm missing to make the cast work would be great.

### Update:

The member looks like the following:

```
 MyType<string> PostalCode =  new MyType<string>();
```

I'm loading the properties with **Dapper** and the methods that were suggested are not being hit. So when the reflection engine tries to load the objects the implicit cast is not firing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your operator is backwards. It supports casting from `MyType<t>` to `t`. You want the other way around. Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for.

```
 private t _value;

 private MyType(t val)
 {
      _value = val;
 }

 public static implicit operator MyType<t>(t obj)
 {
     return new MyType<t>(obj);
 }
```

Using the constructor is optional, I personally just find that cleaner. You could just use the default constructor and set the field explicitly in your operator as well.

Comment: That makes sense. However, the methods are not being hit.

Comment: @Arnej65 Dapper might be trying to do an explicit cast then, which you can also override, change `implicit` to `explicit`.

Comment: I mixed it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898988/map-string-to-guid-with-dapper

Answer (score 1):

Your implicit cast operator is working in the reverse direction to what the error is complaining about, you need to implement the other implicit operator to go from `t` to `MyType<t>`.

You can also do the same with explicit casting (where you do something like `string foo = (string)someObject;`):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4(v=vs.71).aspx